# "Open in Low Resolution" is checked on Retina MacBook Pro checked and greyed out

Tags: macos, applications, resolution, software

ZBrush 2018 opens with high DPI support, but ZBrush 2019 has the "Open in low resolution" checked, and is greyed out so it cannot be changed.

Anybody know what is going on?

Pixologic just suggested checking the permissions, but they are identical to ZBrush 2018. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can you clarify what permissions Pixologic wanted you to check?